# Generating Agents of Same Type with Different Colors by Uniform Distribution - AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling, uniform-distribution, event-simulation

*Hello there,*

*I am trying to add a source that generates agents with different colors that are randomly populated based on a non-uniform distribution. For example, I'd like to see this source generates 50% of the agents having orange or 10% of them lightSkyBlue color.
I have this line so far that randomly selects a color from **availableColors** array. But I need each color to be selected based its associated probability.*

```html
availableColors = { oliveDrab, crimson, orange, lightSkyBlue, darkOrchid }

agent.favoriteColor =
    randomFrom(availableColors);
```

**Any clue? thanks**

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. Maybe take a look here? [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It makes sense for #AnyLogic users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom distribution from the Agent palette with the following properties. In the below, 2 represents "no color". The sum of the number of observations should always be 100 if you are using percentages.

[image]

Then create a function with the following properties and body:
[image]

```
int colorID = colorProbabilities();

if( colorID == 0 ) { return orange;}
else if (colorID == 1 ) { return lightSkyBlue;}
else return null;
```

Finally, you can now use:

```
agent.favoriteColor = colorPicker();
```

This allows you now to customize your distribution at any point to any number of colors and to any probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way around:

1. In the agent type that your Source block creates, add a shape (rectangle...) named `myShapeHavingColor`
2. In the Source block, ensure it creates agents of that type
3. In the Source block, in the "on at Exit" code box, you can now change colors from your desired distributions, for example:

[image]

Comment: The way the code is written is not equivalent to 50% and 10%. It is actually equivalent to 50% and 5% since the second `randomTrue` is "given that the first condition is false", so it's 10% of the remaining 50%. You should have `randomTrue(0.2)` in the second condition for this to be correct.

Comment: I know, it was just an example, hence I said "from your desired distributions". Good flag, thx

Answer (score 0):

Another simple answer if you're not comfortable with coding is to use the select output block. Something as simple as this:
[image]